# Creating multi-line 'String' in a static text of a GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, multiline, matlab-guide

I have a static text in GUI and need to write something like:

```
y1 = A[1]
y2 = A[2]
y3 = A[3]
```

etc. (there is a certain limit, right now this is not important).

Where `y1, y2, y3` are *strings*, and `A[1], A[2], A[3]` are *numbers* in a matrix `A`.

I'm just not sure how to enter a new line in that static text, meaning I'm not sure how to go from `y1` to `y2`.

I know there are a lot of answers to this question on the Internet but I can't find one that suits my needs for some reason.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using `MATLAB-Guide` to create the GUI?

Comment: Yes, I'm a beginner so I prefer using GUIDE.

Comment: Awesome! Works for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the `static-text` is stretched far enough to accommodate those multi-lines text. Here's a demo with some sample values in `A`. The trick is to use a `Nx1 cell array` with each cell representing each such assignment text. The code must make it clear -

```
A = [4 9 22 29 34 47 56 78 100]; %// Assumed as a vector for demo

cellstrg = cell(numel(A),1);
for k = 1:numel(A)
    cellstrg(k) = {['y',num2str(k),' = ' ,num2str(A(k))]};
end
set(handles.text1,'String',cellstrg) %// handles.text1 is tag to that static text
```

You can avoid the for-loops with a `cellfun` approach, which might not be efficient, but just a concise way of achieving the same thing  -

```
cellstrg = strcat('y',cellstr(num2str([1:numel(A)]')),'=',strtrim(cellstr(num2str(A'))))
```

Output on GUI -

[image]