# How to import the entire content of a text file into Edit Text Box of Matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, text-files, matlab-guide, textreader

I have a text file (.txt) that I want insert all containing of it to Matlab GUI and show it in a text box. Sometimes this text box updates when I GUI open it so there isn’t a specified text in it. (It is like a help note for my GUI that has text, numbers etc.) . I want insert whole containing of this text file automatically to my text box in Matlab GUI. What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MATLAB GUIDE for this?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Matlab GUIDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the name of the text file as `file1.txt` and `edit1` as the handles to the text-box, which is `editbox` in the context of `MATLAB GUIDE`, try inserting the following code inside the `OpeningFcn` callback or with some GUI component callback -

```
data1 = importdata('file1.txt','') %// Import all text as a cell array with each cell for each line
set(handles.edit1, 'Max', 2); %// Enable multi-line string input to the editbox
set(handles.edit1,'String',data1) %//  Put the text from text file into the editbox using `String` property
set(handles.edit1,'HorizontalAlignment','left') %// Align the text left-based, as it looks good maybe, but feel free to change it to center or right
```

If the text file is not present in the current directory, provide absolute path to it instead of `'file1.txt'`.

Comment: @user2991243 Most welcome! I learnt few things about editbox myself in the process :)

Comment: @user2991243 Also you might find this other problem relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759822/creating-multi-line-string-in-a-static-text-of-a-gui